# jQuery Twitter/Facebook like page navigation

Tags: jquery, facebook, url-routing

I have really liked how the new Twitter and Facebook have saved page loads by instead loading the content dynamically through ajax. I want to start rolling this out to my sites, but I have no idea where to even start.

Twitter and Facebook now have uri's like this:
http://twitter.com/#!/messages

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// Check if a hash exists already and if so load that page instead.
if(window.location.hash) {
    $("div#content").load(window.location.hash);
} else {
    // load the home page.
    $("div#content").load("http://localhost/home/");
}

// Allow menu to change url hash and load new content.
$('ul#menu li a').click(function() {
    $("div#content").load(window.location.hash);
});

});
```

The html for the menu I have:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>< a href="#">logout</a></li>
    <li>< a href="#!/settings">settings</a></li>
    <li>< a href="#!/messages" class="notify">messages <span>3</span></a></li>
    <li>< a href="#!/profile">profile</a></li>
    <li>< a href="#!/" class="selected">home</a></li></ul>
```

Any idea how Facebook or Twitter does this?

Comment: I'd suggest that you have a read of (the *possible* dupe): [Facebook Style AJAX Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568312/facebook-style-ajax-search), and see if the answers there help you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are just asking about how Ajax works.  The best way to start using Ajax is with jQuery and the best type of page loads you can do are text files.  Try something like this

1) create a file that contains a single letter "A". Name the file "A.txt".

2) create a file that contains a single letter "B". Name the file "B.txt".

3) create a complete HTML page that loads jQuery and name it Test.htm.  In that file, create this code:

```
<input type="button" class="LoadMyDiv" id="ButtonA" value="load A">
<input type="button" class="LoadMyDiv" id="ButtonB" value="load B">


 $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".LoadMyDiv").click(function() {
         $("#Adiv").load("A.txt");
         $("#Bdiv").load("B.txt");
 });
 });
<div id="ThisDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be the best [answer](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/)

hope will help others too.