# Ajax Live Search multiple response at a time

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, response, livesearch

According to this question, we use deboucing to make a live search like facebook

[Facebook Style AJAX Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568312/facebook-style-ajax-search)

But here is my case, when I set the timeout as 300ms, first I type query A and wait for 300ms then an ajax request is triggered, but when waiting for server to response for query A, I do another query B, and after 300ms, the response for query A finally shows up, and then immediately response for query B shows up too, so you see 2 results flashing, how to prevent this? (cancel the first request or something?)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many results you return I see 2 possible actions:

- Don't make a new request but wait for the old one to complete and filter it with the new search value
- Cancel the first request and start another one.

The first method will only work well when the first request returns more items than are displayed.